# Как правильно: пришел или пришли? Замолчал или замолчали?

Tags: окончания

Она ушла в булочную, а Степан с остальными уже пришел(ли) в спортзал.

...а так как он с товарищами наконец-то замолчал(ли), то то-то и то-то...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Общее решение** по правилу Розенталю выглядит так:

Форма мн. числа сказуемого показывает, что в роли подлежащего выступает все сочетание, т.е. **действие приписывается двум взаимосвязанным равноправным субъектам.**

Форма ед. числа сказуемого показывает, что **подлежащим является только сущ. в И. падеже,** а сущ. в Т.падеже выступает в роли дополнения, обозначая **сопутствующее** лицо.

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_04)

2) Для каждого предложения нужно определить равноправность действующих лиц **по ситуации**.

3) ***Она ушла в булочную, а Степан с друзьями уже пришел в спортзал.***

Здесь главные действующие лица — это она и Степан, а друзья относятся к второстепенным персонажам.

Сравнить: ***Она ушла в булочную, а Степан и все остальные уже пришли в спортзал.*** Так будет выглядеть предложение, когда рассматриваются равноправные действия всей компании.

4) **...а так как он и его товарищи наконец-то замолчали...**

Для этого предложения конструкция ***он с товарищами*** не подходит, так как участие в этом действии всех субъектов мыслится как равноправное (а в этом случае нужно употребить местоимение *они*).

Сравнить (неравноправное действие):

В 2000 году **он с друзьями решил** немного погонять по Скандинавии...

Подле него была дочь одного персидского хана, которую **он с братом похитил** из родительского дома...

Answer (score 3):

— Степан пришёл не один. — С кем пришёл Степан? — **Степан** приш**ёл** **с остальными** ребятами. — Ясно. Значит, **Степан и остальные** уже приш**ли** в спортзал.

Comment: А что Вы скажете, Александр, про тот случай, если "остальных" заменить на Васю? Только не в Вашем предложении, а как у Ростислава.

Comment: Хороший вопрос :) "Степан с Васей" в этом предложении перестанет отличаться от "Степана и Васи" ("пришли"). Для сравнения: Степан **пришёл** в спортзал с Васей. Похоже, от контекста зависит распределение ролей в группе пришедших. С "замолчанием" иначе, во всех случаях "они замолчали" сами, а не в придачу Степану.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сказал ***пришёл***. Но *пришли,* если с *"и" (и остальные):*

> Она ушла в булочную, а Степан и остальные уже пришли в спортзал.

Задумался, что будет, если заменить *остальных* на условного *Васю.* И с ним я бы уже сказал ***пришли***. Так что немного сам запутался. :(

Что касается второго предложения, в случае местоимения *он* я уверенно скажу в единственном числе *(замолчал),* а если поставить того же Степана или другое имя, то считаю, что ситуация та же, что и в первом предложении. То есть я предпочёл бы единственное число.